# Bulk str_replace sub-folder names with PHP

Tags: php

I have a lot of subfolders that have spaces in their names (in this example under main folder TEMP, could be folders "folder A" "folder B has many spaces" etc.  I have tried this code to replace all sub folder names spaces with underlines but could someone please tell me why it isn't working?
Cheers.

```
<?php  
 $dir = 'https://www.example.com/image/catalog/TEMP';

 if (is_dir($dir)) {
     if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
         while (($foldername = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
               
             rename($dir.$foldername, str_replace(" ","_",$dir.$foldername));
   
         }
         closedir($dh);
     }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind You cannot list directories by URL and rename them.

So please write at least relative path.

For example if script at root of www:

```
$dir = __DIR__ . DS . 'image/catalog/TEMP';
```

```
<?php
const DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$dir = __DIR__ . DS . 'image/catalog/TEMP';

if (!is_dir($dir)) {
  echo "\n".$dir." is not directory"."\n";
  exit(0);
}

$dh = opendir($dir);

while ($item = readdir($dh)) :
  if ($item === '.' || $item === '..') continue;

  $current = $dir . DS . $item;
  $new = $dir . DS . str_replace(" ", "_", $item);

  if ($current === $new) continue; // nothing to rename

  rename($current, $new);
  echo $current.' => '.$new."\n";
endwhile;

closedir($dh);
```

[image: test image]

Comment: It looks like it should work but for me it didn't.  I checked all my write permissions and that is all good so I'm at a loss at the moment.

Comment: @Kankan2000 I've checked it works as expected and added example. I suspect You've problems with path `$dir` if You're expecting that You'll go by url and list files and replace through url - it's totally wrong. So please add to Your question real path example or at least screenshot to understand what's dir structure and how You're using it in code. Also add at the beginning: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  maybe there is a error which is not visible by settings.

Comment: I've extended code a bit to print that dir is not directory before stopping. also added line where skipping renaming if current and new are same (nothing's changed).

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation, yes the error was on my part, your code works perfectly thanks :)